# Is there a guideline as to when I should pass a collection as an argument or return a new collection?

Tags: language-agnostic, methods, parameters

Suppose I have the following methods:

```
def read(file: str) -> List[str]:
    temp = []
    with open(file) as f_obj:
        for line in f_obj:
            temp.append(line)
    return temp


def append_items_to_list(folders : List[str], file: str):
    with open(file) as f_obj:
        for line in f_obj:
            folders.append(line)


def main():

    source: str = "source.txt"

    directories : List[str] = read(file=source)
    print(len(directories))     

    folderList : List[str] = []
    append_items_to_list(folders=folderList, file=source)
    print(len(folderList))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Both methods read from a file, and appends items to a `List`. The first method creates a temporary `List` and returns it, while the second accepts a `List` as a parameter, and appends to it.

Is there a guideline that states which one is preferable? Are there any underlying problems I don't see that I should be concerned about with either one?

I guess you would have to look at why you need to construct a new `List`, in this case, I don't need to construct a new `List`, I can just use the second method.

**Clarification**:

It seems the general answer is to return a new `List`, but I've narrowed down my problem a little more.

```
def do_work(source: Path, destination: Path):
    # do some work with the folders.

def create_list_of_empty_folders(folders : List[str], folder: Path):
    # Check if folder is empty, if so, append it to the List.

def cleanup(folders_to_remove: List[Path]):
    # Remove all folders in the List from the HD.


def main():

    portableHD = Path("Path\\to\\HD")
    USB = Path("Path\\to\\USB")

    empty_folders : List[Path] = []

    for folder in portableHD.iterdir():
        do_work(source=folder, destination=USB)
        create_list_of_empty_folders(folders=empty_folders, folder=folder)

     # Outside of the for loop we can safely remove the empty folders.
    cleanup(folders_to_remove=empty_folders)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this context, I have no choice but to pass a `List` and a `folder` to my function. Obviously, I could write out the code in the for loop without the use of a function, but let's assume I want to write clean maintainable code.

In my first example, I don't really need to use function, I can read and append the data to a `List` directly in the `main` method:

```
def main():

    file: str = "source.txt"

    folders : List[str] = []

    with open(file) as f_obj:
        for line in f_obj:
            folders.append(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But let's assume more work needs to be done with each of these folders, so I refactor my code and create smaller methods, why is returning a temporary `List` from a function more desirable?

> Does your function really have to know that the goal of the caller is
>   to append ?

Why can't my function know the caller wants to append to a `List`? After all I did break down the code into smaller functions, one of which appends to a `List`. Even if I were to rename my method to `append(folders : List[str], file: str)`, the function parameters indicate what I want to append.

Comment: Even better: return a generator. If I want to, I can pay the cost to materialize it into a list. Or maybe I just need the first 3 elements, so I only want to pay the price for those.

Comment: @Alexander - I updated my question with a little more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal guideline like that.

If we ignore language specific aspects such as language idioms, language capabilities, performance or programming paradigm (i.e. functional orientation) there are a few rules of thumb left.

Considering the **broadest reuse possibility** of the function you want to implement, depending on the **semantic** of your operation:

- is it about modifying a list owned by someone else ? In this case you’d go for passing the list as input/output argument.
- is it about enriching or transforming a list owned by someone else but where the modification is not necessarily the goal to be achieved ? In this case, pass the list as input argument and return a new result list.
- is it about producing a new list ? just return the output list without getting an input list.

In your example, it’s about producing a new list of files in a folder. Does your function really have to know that the goal of the caller is to append ? Or could it work esually well without considering the ownership of the list ? So return a new list and let the caller decide what is to be done.

**Clarification**

These are rules of thumb, but for every program you write, the design decisions are yours.

In your specific use case, you decide to break up a large function in smaller ones. This is a design decision. So you are in principle in first case: the list is owned by the caller who is responsible for the overall processing, and your function is only doing a part of it.

There’s nothing wrong with that and you could stop here. Then comes the point about possible reuse. Personally, I can see plenty of uses for a list of folders in other cases also. This is why I would revise my design decision and refactor the function to produce a new list, and let the caller do the append. If you don’t see opportunities of reuse, let it be.

If there is more to to with the list, I would still try to keep it general, and let the caller apply a function to the elements of the list (the function could be to rename, to touch date, to move, to print, ...). But again, maybe the possibilities I see are not relevant in your case. Ultimately the choice is yours. No rule shall dictate you the choice, if you have founded reasons to do otherwise.

Comment: I updated my question with a little more clarification.

Comment: @ConsoleGeek I’ve added a clarification. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

The guideline I'd recommend is:

Don't put unnecessary restrictions on your user.

If you take a list as a parameter, the user has to create a list and pass it in, even if they don't want more items than the items you're supplying.  That makes your code more of a hassle to use than it would be otherwise.

Comment: I updated my question with a little more clarification.

Comment: But you would still need to create a `List` if the function returns a temporary `List`.